# $\square\diamond\varphi$ valid in a Model with a single world with no successor

Tags: logic, modal-logic

$\square\varphi$ is valid in model M that has a single world w, and w has no outgoing arcs(it has no successor). $\square\varphi$ is **vacuously truth** at w.

Would $\square\diamond\varphi$ be also valid in this same Model M that has a single world w, and w has no outgoing arcs(it has no successor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Every* formula of the form $\square\psi$ is valid at $w$ (because $w$ has no successors). So, this also holds if $\psi$ happens to be of the form $\diamond\varphi$.

Comment: What do you mean with: if $\varphi$ holds at w(do you mean that $\diamond\varphi$ has to hold at w to make $\square\diamond\varphi$ hold at w)? 
Isn't it that $\square\diamond\varphi$ is vacuously truth at w?

Comment: I don't understand why you're asking about 'if $\varphi$ holds at $w$'; I'm not saying that anywhere. The point is, indeed, that $\square\diamond\varphi$ is vacuously true at $w$.

Comment: I misinterpreted it, thank you for you help!